# Incorrect state of ViewPager2 Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I am facing a problem with `ViewPager2` and `FragmentStateAdapter`

Here is my default home screen:

[image]

When some condition changed, I am choosing another adapter for `ViewPager2` on `onViewCreated`, so it's now should looks like:

[image]

But somehow, its just shows previous fragments, but with changed count of fragments

**My adapters:**

*When 4 pages need:*

```
class OrgUserPagerAdapter(fragment: Fragment) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    override fun getItemCount() = OrgUserPages.values().size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (OrgUserPages.values()[position]) {
            OrgUserPages.OPPORTUNITIES -> OpportunitiesFragment()
            OrgUserPages.NEWS -> NewsFeedFragment()
            OrgUserPages.CHATS -> ChatsFragment()
            OrgUserPages.PROFILE -> ProfileFragment()
        }
    }
}
```

*When 3 pages need:*

```
class PendingUserPagerAdapter(fragment: Fragment) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    override fun getItemCount() = PendingUserPages.values().size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (PendingUserPages.values()[position]) {
            PendingUserPages.OPPORTUNITIES -> OpportunitiesFragment()
            PendingUserPages.CHATS -> ChatsFragment()
            PendingUserPages.PROFILE -> ProfileFragment()
        }
    }
}
```

Change condition:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val currentOrgIsPendingOrHidden = mPresenter.getCurrentOrgState()
               
        pager.adapter = if (currentOrgIsPendingOrHidden)
            PendingUserPagerAdapter(this@HomeFragment)
        else
            OrgUserPagerAdapter(this@HomeFragment)
}
```

Also, all work as expected after app restart.

Comment: Can you show the could where you setup the viewpager2? Normally if you want to change adapter you would use `viewpager2.setAdapter(newAdapter)` again. If you are doing what I think you are doing and just changing the contents of a variable where the viewpager thinks it's adapter is then you are doing nothing to tell the viewpager2 the contents of the adapter has changed (though the`getItemCount()` will be used from the new instance of the class as you change pages therefore it thinks the original set of pages now has one less item)

Comment: @Andrew Check last code fragment, this is the only place I set new adapter

Comment: Something is missing from your code snippets I don't quite understand yet. So `onViewCreated` is usually called as part of a Fragment creation process that is hosting the viewpager2 which is in an Activity. This is only called once on hosting Fragment creation, and that Fragment is only created once by the hosting Activity. So as you say it works when you restart the App (The Fragment and Activity get recreated) but I don't see how it would every be changed once first setup correctly.
I suggest that you show more code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I am encountering the exact same behavior.  From what I can see, the problem happens when the ViewPager2 is recreated from a savedInstanceState Bundle.  I haven't been able to figure out a solution yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue today and was able to solve my problem.  Because FragmentStateAdapter is a RecyclerView adapter, you have to remember to override containsItem and getItemId if the elements in the adapter can change.  I had implemented it the same as you, and this works in almost all cases.  However, in cases where the ViewPager is recreated from a savedInstanceState bundle, it does not work correctly.

I think this is because the ViewPager2 tries to re-use old fragments since they have the same itemId.

Comment: can you post a code snippet for this please?